# References for this theorem

Tags: derivatives, reference-request, taylor-expansion

Here is the statement (it is a sort of a division theorem) :

> Let $f\in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f(0)=0$  and
>   $g:\mathbb{R^*}\to \mathbb{R},\ x\mapsto \frac{f(x)}{x}$ and
>   $g(0)=f'(0)$. Then $g\in\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\forall
>  n \in \mathbb{N}$ : $g^{(n)}(0)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(0)}{n+1}$.

I was wondering if there are references for this statement ? I just found the statement as an exercise on the internet.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

You can write
$$f(x)=\int_0^x f'(t)\>dt= x\int_0^1 f'(\tau x)\>d\tau\ .$$
Then
$$g(x):=\int_0^1 f'(\tau x)\>d\tau$$is $C^\infty$, satisfies $g(x)={f(x)\over x}$ when $x\ne0$, and Leibniz' rule gives
$$g^{(n)}(x)=\int_0^1 \tau^n\, f^{(n+1)}(\tau x)\>d\tau\ ,$$
which implies $$g^{(n)}(0)=f^{(n)}(0)\int_0^1 \tau^n\>d\tau={f^{(n+1)}(0)\over n+1}\ .$$

Comment: Thank you but I have to justify the derivative under $\int$ ? Moreover are there any references for this result ?

Comment: I learnt something with this $f'(\tau x)$ substitution. Finding the formula for $g^{(n)}(0)$ is the easy part provided $g$ is n-times derivable, but I was wondering how to prove $g$ is actually $C^\infty$.

Comment: @zwim an induction enables to conclude